# setting .htaccess file in slim

Tags: php, slim

I am having issues redirecting to index.php in my slim app with .htaccess file. 
 Routes work if I add the index.php at the end of the URL

So `slimapp.dev/hello/myname` gets error

```
Not Found The requested URL /hello/myname was not found on this server.
```

while `slimapp.dev/index.php/hello/myname` works

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php [QSA,L]
```

I am using Apache 2 on Ubuntu 18.04

File structure

```
public_html
           |_index.php
           |_ vendor
           |_.htaccess
```

virtualHost 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

If I use the `php -S localhost:3000` it works as expected but if I use the Apache web server, I most add the index.php to the end of the URL to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Sanity check: In your Apache settings, where are you pointing Document Root?

Comment: Also, are you sure that your virtual host's `AllowOverride` settings are correct? Just to be sure, can you post your vhost block?

Comment: In addition to what @maiorano84 said, does your .htaccess have a space between the carat (^) and "index.php" like it does in the example? You might try removing the space if so.

Comment: @Hayden That's a good catch. The extra space may very well be causing the problem OP is seeing.

Comment: Enable rewrite `a2enmod rewrite` in Apache.

Comment: @maiorano84 Document root to  ` DocumentRoot /var/www/html/slimapi-dev.com/public_html ` on virtual host

Comment: @FAEWZX `a2nmod rewrite` changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong.This is quite simple with just two lines of code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myname/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Read the question. Your answer has nothing to do with what OP is asking.

Comment: @Mariorano84, This is simple htaccess rule and what i think is foliwe83 wants to spoof the url to "slimapp.dev/hello/myname" rather than "slimapp.dev/hello/" which is root directory of the app. That's it.

Comment: Again: Read the question. OP is not asking to spoof any URL. His problem is that Apache is not properly deferring any requests to `index.php` automatically, so none of his URLs work without the presence of `index.php` in the URL structure. Even further, all your answer does is remove the `myname` prefix from all URLs, which doesn't even satisfy what you think he's asking.